# Check validity of username and password before authentication process

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.2.5. I use ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider for my authentication provider. But I want to check my username and password before authenticating through Active Directory. 
For example, Before authentication process starts via Active Directory, I want to check that username and password are not equal and there is no space in them or their size is not smaller than special size.

**Update:**
Spring Security does not allow empty username and/or password and raise this exception:
Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials.

I have looking around in different filters and I think I should do this checking in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter but I am not sure and I don't know how to do it. I highly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
/Samaneh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spring Security should error if the user attempts to submit an empty username or password. As far as testing password criteria prior to LDAP authentication attempt, that seems inherently insecure. By testing a precondition you may give an attacker insight as to what the password may be. Additionally, short circuiting the LDAP binding attempt would effectively circumvent any maximum invalid attempt threshold configured in Active Directory.

Simply put, when it comes to authentication, we don't want to give the user any specific details other than the username and password you provided were wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MarkVieira. As you said, Spring Security does not allow empty username and password and before it calls Active Directory, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter raise this exception: <br/>Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials. <br/>But I want Spring Security also check if username and password are equal or if there is space in them. I know I can do this in other ways like javascript but I want to have all of these constraints in one place and handled by Spring Security.

Comment: As you mentioned @MarkVieira, it can be input to attackers if the error message reveals details of these constraints. But I am thinking to have only one error message for login failed.

Comment: Doing short circuit logic like this can still expose a vulnerability in the way of a timing attack. Additionally, the issue with a user's account possibly not being locked out would still be a problem. I am curious to know what your use case is? Why not let AD simply authenticate their credentials? In any case, your best best would probably be to extend `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and possibly place your logic in an overridden `setDetails()` method that did your checks and threw a `BadCredentialsException` or else simply call the super implementation.

Comment: You have a good point about being locked out by AD. I will do some tests but I think I follow your advice and let AD handle it. Thanks for your time.